# Using Jquery POST() method not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a form something like this

```
    <form id="logReg" action="<?php echo $url?>" method="post">
    <input name="im_user" type="text" class="valores" id="im_user" placeholder="Email" style="height:35px; font-size:16px;" maxlength="255" />
    <input name="im_password" type="password" class="valores" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" style="height:35px; font-size:16px;" id="im_password" />
    <input name="inputAds" type="submit" value="Ingresar" />
</form>
```

Its a login form . Then I am using Post() method of Jquery to send the login details to the server everything working fine . But the problem is in the console when i debug the response of the post method . I see the my password and id is visible.

Ajax script is

```
$("#logReg").submit(function (event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
     console.log("request being sent");
    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $(this),
        im_user = $form.find("input[name='im_user']").val(),
        im_password = $form.find("input[name='im_password']").val(),
        url = $form.attr("action");
    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post(url, {
        im_user: im_user,
        im_password: im_password
    });
    //Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function (data) {
        var content = $(data).find("#content");
        $("#logRegResult").empty().append(content);
    });

});
```

I am very new to Ajax method . Can any one explain me how can I hide the password and id from displaying in the console .

Thanks

Comment: you can't do that... to prevent man in the middle attaches use `https`... but still it will be visible in the conosle

Comment: @ArunPJohny but POST method is meant to send the password without being displayed right :(. I have very little knowledge Ajax so can you give me some details How I can use the AJax call for Login forms

Comment: no.. post is not suppose to do anything like that... even in a non ajax post request the form body can be inspected using the net tab

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh! I was unaware of that . So how do you suggest I should send the login credential to the server . I use php as in my server side language .

Comment: the only thing that you should do is to use https.... other than that just showing the creds in console is not a problem... so that a man in the middle won't be able to view it

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you very much I will add that in the url .So  what I have understood from this is that . If I am user and I tried login in the website its only me who can see the password in the console .

Comment: yes... unless your browser is not compromised(may be a malware can see it but there is nothing you can do about it)

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks bro very much :) . I have now a better understanding of $_Post method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign some value to a variable, the left hand code is executed, then that final value is assigned to the variable.

In this case it's the jQuery post object which has already sent a request, with out a specified callback. You should specify the callback like so.

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    im_user: im_user,
    im_password: im_password
}).done(function (data) {
    var content = $(data).find("#content");
    $("#logRegResult").html(content);
});
```

*** Note: as others have mentioned, this is not a secure method for sending your passwords.

Also, it seems a little odd to me to be looking for an element by id with-in the return data. Make sure that part is actually functioning. You probably want the html to be properly formatted before it's sent back from the server.